# Doctrine: can I use SQL to create my tables?

Tags: database, orm, doctrine

I'm looking at exploring Doctrine. Seems like the examples I have found assumes Doctrine will create the tables I need. I like to design my databases using MySQL Workbench. Can I just give  the MySQL create script to Doctrine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use Doctrine2 ORM you should forget about sql totally. ORM is object relational mapper in its nature all you should know about is your objects and relations between them. And I think that answers your question. If you use ORM design your database using objects, not sql.

Comment: What about my ERDs? I like having a visual representation of my database.

Comment: I do not know, which tools could be used to represent your ORM schema, basically its relations and inheritance between objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our tool [Skipper - formerly ORM Designer](http://www.skipper18.com/) to design visual representation of the objects and their relations, fill in the ORM properties and then generate complete schema files directly from the visual model (I'm chief developer of this tool).

You don't have to deal wit the SQL and actual database level, it will be taken care of by Doctrine or Doctrine2.